# PHP MySql: how save timestamp UTC, like "Flickr"?

Tags: php, mysql

For default i'm using this snippet in my codes

```
setlocale(LC_TIME,'it_IT');
```

and I did save all my dates in mysql in a timestamp format.

In a view of make international one of my codes, i would like to save in MySQL a similar value

```
2013-07-12T07:59:27+0000
```

but of course with the +2 hours. So a Polish user will have a +3 and so on...

What's the best field for mysql to store that value? I need also to work with date, from PHP and/or from directly MySQL (for example)

```
SELECT id WHERE data BEETWEN [...]
```

Of course if I start with correct way, i don't need to change in future all my dbs, codes, etc...

Thank you very much!

Comment: If I understand, you can store as [unixtime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) in your db and show in the frontend in the format you want

Comment: UHm.... In effect unixtime is time-zone independent, and this is perfect for me. Visualization via phpmyadmin or admsql of a timestamp field is dependent of system variables? So, am i sure using timestamp in mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me is better store date time as [UNIXTIME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), it avoid the time difference between user from different locations.

You can use:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name 
WHERE field_name 
BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013-07-12 07:59:27') 
AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013-07-13 07:59:27')
```

to get the Date Range

Comment: I think that your answer is perfect ;) Please, solve only my doubt about MYSQL visualization....

Comment: what are you referring when you say `MYSQL visualization`

Comment: timestamp is tz independent. Opening DB with phpmyadmin or admsql i see data in italian format (data and hour). Is it only because mysql read that it is in an italian server? So if i move mysql db on an american server i'll see different data/hour?

Comment: with unixtime you avoid that, unixtime is stored as INT and you see something like this `1382035045` in the database

Comment: Get a look to this image (from adminer / admsql.php, alternative at phpmyadmin). Mysqli Field is a timestamp but i see it like a human date  https://www.dropbox.com/s/q8x53hkx6tugb7z/Immagine.png

Comment: There you have timestamp, that data is generated in mysql server, always has the configuration of your server or your [default-time-zone='timezone'](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html) setting in wherever country your server is